# X quits when certain web pages are opened with web browsers

Tags: debian, x11

Whenever I visit https://github.com/vinc/level (as one example), X quits, and am taken to login screen. This happens with Firefox and Chromium.

I use dwm, and following is "~/.xsession":

```
# apps
emacs --daemon || true
firefox &
nm-applet &
trayer --edge top --align right --widthtype request --distance 19 &
alacritty --option font.size=6                    --command tmux &
alacritty --option font.size=6 --class Emacs      --command emacsclient --tty &
alacritty --option font.size=6 --class Monitoring --command tmux &
xss-lock slock &

# settings
xset b off
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Super_L"
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=0 TapButton3=2 MaxDoubleTapTime=100 HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
syndaemon -dti 1

# battery, loadavg, and clock
monitor &

exec dwm
```

Following is "~/.xsession-errors":

```
Xsession: X session started for tshepang at Sat 25 Sep 2021 19:01:22 SAST
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/tshepang/.Xauthority
localuser:tshepang being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=tshepang
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/tshepang
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=tshepang
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_ZA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/tshepang/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm/data/tshepang
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/usr/bin/fish
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=lightdm-xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/tshepang
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading savehist...
Loading savehist...done
Loading semantic...
Loading semantic...done
Loading paren...
Loading paren...done
Starting Emacs daemon.
Unable to start the daemon.
Another instance of Emacs is running the server, either as daemon or interactively.
You can use emacsclient to connect to that Emacs process.
Saving tag summaries...
Saving tag summaries...done
Error: server did not start correctly

(nm-applet:7516): dbind-WARNING **: 19:01:23.844: AT-SPI: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(nm-applet:7516): libnotify-WARNING **: 19:01:28.134: Failed to connect to proxy

(nm-applet:7516): nm-applet-WARNING **: 19:01:28.136: Failed to show notification: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

(firefox:7515): Gdk-WARNING **: 19:05:59.579: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING

(firefox:7515): Gdk-WARNING **: 19:06:14.451: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING

(firefox:7515): Gdk-WARNING **: 19:06:39.978: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING

(firefox:7515): Gdk-WARNING **: 19:06:55.061: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING

(firefox:7515): Gdk-WARNING **: 19:08:25.605: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING

(firefox:7515): Gdk-WARNING **: 19:08:25.622: Error converting selection from UTF8_STRING
```

Hardware:

```
❯ sudo lshw -short
H/W path             Device     Class          Description
==========================================================
                                system         Latitude 7480 (07A0)
/0                              bus            0FFTYF
/0/0                            memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/45                           memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/45/0                         memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/45/1                         memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/49                           memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/4a                           memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/4b                           memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/4c                           processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/100                          bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                        display        Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
/0/100/4                        generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14                       bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0          usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/5                   multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/0/a                   generic        5880
/0/100/14/1          usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                     generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
/0/100/15                       generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                     generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/15.2                     generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2
/0/100/16                       communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17            scsi2      storage        Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/17/0.0.0      /dev/sda   disk           256GB INTEL SSDSCKKF25
/0/100/17/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1  volume         487MiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/100/17/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2  volume         237GiB Extended partition
/0/100/17/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5  volume         237GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/100/1c                       bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c/0                     generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.2                     bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0        wlp2s0     network        Wireless 8265 / 8275
/0/100/1c.4                     bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1f                       bridge         Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                     memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                     multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                     bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/100/1f.6          enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
/0/1                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                            system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                            generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/4                            input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/5                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                            system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                              power          DELL MYJ9689
/2                   docker0    network        Ethernet interface
```

Last lines of `dmesg`:

```
[26980.113797] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from e8:65:d4:3e:08:55 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[26980.517237] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[26988.008352] wlp2s0: authenticate with e8:65:d4:3e:08:55
[26988.019078] wlp2s0: send auth to e8:65:d4:3e:08:55 (try 1/3)
[26988.021667] wlp2s0: authenticated
[26988.022386] wlp2s0: associate with e8:65:d4:3e:08:55 (try 1/3)
[26988.025668] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from e8:65:d4:3e:08:55 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=1)
[26988.029811] wlp2s0: associated
[26988.047411] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

Last lines of "/var/log/Xorg.0.log":

```
[ 26980.068] (II) event6  - Power Button: device removed
[ 26980.095] (II) event4  - Power Button: device removed
[ 26980.114] (II) event5  - Sleep Button: device removed
[ 26980.142] (II) event11 - Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate: device removed
[ 26980.238] (II) event1  - DualPoint Stick: device removed
[ 26980.278] (II) event7  - Intel HID events: device removed
[ 26980.294] (II) event8  - Intel HID 5 button array: device removed
[ 26980.318] (II) event10 - Dell WMI hotkeys: device removed
[ 26980.366] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[ 26980.390] (II) event12 - Video Bus: device removed
[ 26980.455] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.455] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.455] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.456] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.457] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 26980.560] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I am running latest Debian testing.

Comment: Debian's software stack is quite outdated (unless you're using Debian testing/unstable). Maybe you could try using something newer?

Comment: I run latest Debian testing

Comment: Anything in the kernel log, or in Xorg.0.log? If the X server eats an illegal access, or is killed by the OOM killer, that would show up there.

Comment: @SimonRichter I've updated the post

Comment: Hmm, so this is a normal X shutdown, so it believes the session is ending, which happens either when no clients are left (unlikely in your case), or when the xsession script terminates. Since the script was replaced by dwm, that makes the most likely issue a dwm crash.

Comment: @SimonRichter it does look like it has something to do with dwm indeed... xfce4 has no such problem.

Comment: I suspect the emoji in the title of the page you provided - does [this page](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) also cause the issue?

Comment: @PeterF I use a different wm now (pernrose), but I plan to try that page later (with dwm)

Comment: @PeterF just tried the page, and yeah, I see the same problem

Comment: It seems pretty likely you're seeing [this issue](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/FAQ.html#l224). Does the error they describe show up in your Xorg.log? As far as a solution goes, you could try switching around fonts or using a [patched version of Xft](https://github.com/uditkarode/libxft-bgra).

Comment: I don't remember seeing such an error on Xorg.log, but it looks like you are correct, so maybe you can submit such an answer.

Comment: I had the exact same problem using dwm and vivaldi. It seemed random, but thank you for pointing the root cause. Whenever I go to a site with emoji in the title, dwm crashes.